# lumia 640 windows 10 mobile broken power button

Tags: windows-10, windows-mobile

The power button on my Lumia 640 is broken, luckily I have double tap to wake setting active so I can still use my phone daily.

Also luckily that the phone power up when connected to the charger so I have a way to power it on after swapping the battery.

The problem is sometimes I want to restart the phone. Right now they only way is to do  battery pull which is not a clean restart.

Is there a way to trigger windows restart without power button in Lumia 640?

I am running windows 10 mobile build 10.0.14393.1066.

When googling "restart Lumia 640" or "restart Windows 10 mobile" it is all pointing to factory reset instead of a restart or power off and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third-party apps aren't generally granted enough permissions to do a reboot, so I don't know of any Store apps with this ability, but you could do it with a sideloaded (homebrew) application.

Alternatively, there are a few operations that require the phone to reboot after doing them. For example, changing the display scaling factor (Settings -> System -> Display -> "Size of text, apps, and items on this display") will do it. Interesting, you don't even have to actually change anything; just hit the Apply button then approve the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party apps to restart/power off your phone. Such apps are easily available through store. For instance, I personally use [Power Options](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/power-options/9nblggh4tm3h) on my 535 running W10M though you can have other apps too.